# Python 3.9 keyboard.record()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Возник вопрос:

В модуле `keyboard` имеется функция записи действий с клавиатуры (`start_recording - stop_recording`), по окончании записи данные представляются в типе `list` и их можно записать в переменную.

Вопрос в том, как бы записать эти данные с записи в файл, да так чтоб при открытии в следующий раз `list` сохранился для чтения модулем `keyboard` (функция: `play()`). Или же имеются способы по восстановлению `list` из строки?...

```
import keyboard,json
#нажмите k для активации записи клавиш с клавиатуры пк
keyboard.wait('k')
keyboard.start_recording()
keyboard.wait('l')
a=keyboard.stop_recording()
# здесь тип переменной a list
with open('name.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(str(a))
with open('name.txt','r') as f:
    b = f.read(json.loads(f.read()))
#при присваивании b ошибка.
```

`keyboard` устанавливается на win: `pip install keyboard`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

допустим

```
events = [keyboard.KeyboardEvent(0,0)]
```

тогда можно сохранить как

```
with open('list.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.writelines( [ ke.to_json()+'\n' for ke in events ] )
```

прочитать обратно

```
import json

with open('list.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    events = [ keyboard.KeyboardEvent(**json.loads(js)) for js in f.readlines()]
```

Comment: как я мог забыть что так можно было использовать их же метод при чтении... спасибо большое, вопрос до конца решил добавив в код: `with open('list.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.writelines( [ ke.to_json() for ke in events ] ) `--> `with open('list.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.writelines( [ ke.to_json() +'\n' for ke in events ] )` (перенос на новую строку).

Comment: да, \n забыл..)

Comment: а можно как то так же, но в библиотеке mouse? там отсутствует встроенная функция как в keyboard, а с json не очень дружу ещё.

Comment: Смотри конструктор объекта. `help( Class. __init__)` там указанны параметры. Эти параметры вытаскиваешь через атрибуты и создавай словарик. Дальше словарик в dumps. Посмотри ещё pickle - оно может сохранять почти всё что угодно, но формат нечитаемый

Comment: да-с, спасибо, осуществил.